# React Native Maps not rerendering Markers on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react native maps for displaying a map in my application, and this map should display markers that are fetched from a database online. When the map is mounted, and after fetching the marker data location points, I am updating a state containing the array of marker points, however, the markers do not get rendered after setting the state. Is there any work around in this? Here's a sample code:

P.S. This only occurs in iOS.

```
const [markerPoints, setMarkerPoints] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    getMarkerPoints()
}, [])

const getMarkerPoints = callback => {
    axios
        .get(
            'some end point',
        )
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setMarkerPoints(res.data.results)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

const renderMarkers = () => {
    return markerPoints.map((place, index) => {
        return (
            <Marker
                key={index}
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: place.geometry.location.lat,
                    longitude: place.geometry.location.lng,
                }}
             />
        )
    }
}

return (
    <MapView
        ref={map}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        region={curRegion}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={false}
        onRegionChangeComplete={onMapRegionChangeComplete}
        customMapStyle={mapStyles}
    >
        {renderMarkers()}
    </MapView>
)
```